# can we use both Message Security and http security to providing security for both asmx client and WCF client?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

we cannot use Message Security for asmx client, so i want to know there is a way to use both Message Security and http security to providing security for both asmx client and WCF client??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You do this by creating two different endpoints.  In your case, one for your ASMX client and another for your WCF Client.

For your ASMX Client, you will use the basicHttpBinding with transport security.  Here is the sample from the SDK showing how to configure it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752256(v=vs.110).aspx

For your WCF Client, there are multiple bindings you could use.  The most common is the wsHttpBinding.  By default, it uses message security already. Here are some samples from the SDK for this one.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752237(v=vs.110).aspx

You didn't indicate what kind of credentials (if any) you wanted.  So, that will be another decision you will have to make.  That will be obvious though as you go through the samples I linked to.